# ES2015 function definition with implicit argument

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to translate the following from ES2015 to vanilla javascript:

fileA.js

```
export const checkout = ({ dispatch }) => {
  dispatch(types.CHECKOUT_REQUEST)
}
```

fileB.js

```
import checkout;
checkout();
```

So far (using https://babeljs.io/repl/) I have:

fileA2015.js:

```
module.exports = {
  checkout: function (_ref) {
    dispatch = _ref.dispatch;
    dispatch(types.CHECKOUT_REQUEST)
  }
};
```

But I cannot figure out what to pass to `checkout` in fileB to have access to the correct `_ref`. What is this and where does it come from?

Comment: Uh, that *is* vanilla JavaScript, no framework involved?

Comment: If you are passing nothing to `checkout()`, the function will fail at trying to access the `.dispatch` property. Regardless whether it's written in ES6 or transpiled. I suppose you actually want to use `checkout({dispose(req){ console.log(req); }})`.

Comment: Also, note that `import checkout;` is not valid statement it should be ended with `from`: `import checkout from 'path/to/checkout.module';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const checkout = ({ dispatch }) => {
  dispatch(types.CHECKOUT_REQUEST)
}
```

In the above function you are destructuring an object, which is expected to have a `dispatch` property. Where in `dispatch` is a callback function.

when you pass in the `data` object as a parameter, because of `{ dispatch }`, which destructures the object that is passed in, it is expected to have `dispatch` property.

```
var data = {
   dispatch: (type) => {
       .......
   }
};
```

So when `checkout` method is referenced and invoked in `fileB.js`, then you will have to pass in the data object at this point.

**fileB.js**

```
var data = {
       dispatch: (type) => {
           .......
       }
    };
import checkout;
checkout(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's note a few things here:

```
export const checkout = ({ dispatch }) => {
    dispatch(types.CHECKOUT_REQUEST)
}
```

In the code above, `checkout()` is a function that expects a single parameter -- specifically an object with the property `dispatch`. `dispatch` is also expected to be a function.

If you don't pass any parameters to `checkout()` (or an object that doesn't have a `dispatch` property), `dispatch` will be undefined.

Therefore you need to pass something like:

```
checkout({ dispatch: function(){} })
```